# color:none; alternative

Tags: html, css

I have a link where its text colour will be applied via either `.light` or `.dark`. This link also has a text colour applied on it when hovered over which I cannot remove style (but I can modify it). I want the colour of the text to not change when the user hovers over the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/nCt58/1/

```
<h2><a href="resume" class="light">Resume</a></h2>

a:hover { color:#ff0000; } //cannot remove this style
.light { color:#888; }
.dark { color:#000; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add another selector to override `a:hover`:

```
.light, .light:hover { color:#888; }
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nCt58/4/**

Comment: What's so bad about using '!important', just curious?

Comment: @Self_Taught_Programmer I think it is because `!important` over rides all other styles so it becomes a pain when debugging.

Comment: @Self_Taught_Programmer: Take a look here: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the !important property.

```
.light {color:#888 !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
a:hover { color:#222222 !important; }
```

Given `#222222` it's the normal color when not hovered.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same color for the hover state as the normal state. Like so:

```
.light, a.light:hover{ color:#888}
.dark, a.dark:hover { color:#000; }
```